# SQL. Apply business rules hierarchically

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

SQL2008. I have float values in a table which need to be overriden folowing set of rules. Rules are in another table.

However the rules are hierarchical i.e. - **I need to apply most strict of all suitable rules per each row in main table.**

Here is the example... Rules table (B and C can be NULLS)

```
A    B    C    Value
1    2    3    100
1    2    NULL 80
1    NULL NULL 60

Main Table
A     B     C     Value OverridenValue
1     2     3     1     100
1     2     2     2     80
1     3     1     3     60
3     1     3     4     4    <- no override as no rule found
NULL  NULL  NULL  5     5    <- no override as no rule found
```

**I need a scalar function ie fnGetOverridenValue(@A int, @B int, @C int) Returns float**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select m.A, m.B, m.C, m.[Value],
  Case 
    When Not IsNull(r1.Value) Then r1.Value
    When Not IsNull(r2.Value) Then r2.Value
    When Not IsNull(r3.Value) Then r3.Value
    Else m.[Value]
  End as Overriddenvalue
From
  MainTable m
  Left Join RulesTable r1 on m.A=r1.A and m.B=r1.B and m.C=r1.C
  Left Join RulesTable r2 on m.A=r2.A and m.B=r2.B and r2.C is NULL
  Left Join RulesTable r3 on m.A=r3.A and r3.B is NULL and r3.C is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a Priority column to the RulesTable with 1 for the first rule and so on.

```
select top 1 from RulesTable
where A=@A 
and (B=@B or @B is null and B is null)
and (C=@C or @C is null and C is null)
order by priority
```